# Smooth scrolling JavaScript affecting Modal functionality

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I am using the following JavaScript to execute a smooth scroll for my page.

```
$(function(){
    $('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function() {
        if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
            var target = $(this.hash);
            target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
            if (target.length) {
                $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: target.offset().top
                }, 1000);
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

This works fine, but it has an undesired affect on my modal, as in it prevents the modal from opening.
My HTML for my scroll:

```
<a href="#location" class="btn btn-circle">
    <i class="fa fa-5x fa-angle-double-down animated"></i>
</a>
```

And for my modal:

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" class="collapsed"  href="#1">
                    <span>Press for magic</span>
                </a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse panel-collapse" id="1">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <p>Some magic here...</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is there a way to modify the JavaScript to only have an effect on the scrolling and to leave the modal alone?

Comment: Have you tried replacing the a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"]) with a classname and giving your link a classname like <a class="hashscroll" href="#location" class="btn btn-circle">

Comment: That worked perfect! Thank you @DrinkinPeople If you want to write that up, I'll accept your answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace the `a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])` in your click function with a classname and then put this classname in your `<a>` tag like so:

```
$(function(){
    $('.hashscroll').click(function() {
        if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
            var target = $(this.hash);
            target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
            if (target.length) {
                $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: target.offset().top
                }, 1000);
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

and

```
<a class="hashscroll" href="#location" class="btn btn-circle">
    <i class="fa fa-5x fa-angle-double-down animated"></i>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't animate the whole page.
Just animate what you want to move.

```
<body>
    <div class="animateThis"></div>
    <div class="modal"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more? Are you saying to wrap the scroll in another tag and then modify the javascript to only affect this tag?

Comment: That is correct. You are moving the whole page with your code. $('html, body').animate({ . If you want the modal to stay in one spot it must be separate. So break the page up into two elements and handle each element individually.  You are bordering on web application at this point. Depending on how involved this page is, you may want to look into a framework.